# What is the best way to authenticate user in Firestore without interface (for example, from backend, cron job, etc.)

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Scenario**:

1. I have a file name `cron.php` on my server that runs every 5 minutes to perform a task, for example, sending emails, if they were scheduled. If there is an email needs sending, `cron.php` will perform a HTTP request to the Google Cloud Function (see below).
2. I have a Google Cloud Functions setup to accept the email parameters and perform the email sending.
3. I have a Firestore database which stores user's quota as to how many emails they can send a day.

Now, from Google Cloud Functions, it would need to track and update the quota's from the user when it receives a HTTPS request to send email. In order to accurately track the user's quota, I would need to log in as that user from `cron.php` somehow to pass the token back to the Google Cloud Functions for verification. However, it has been advised to me that Firebase Admin wasn't meant for the server to log in as a user.

**Question #1**: So what is a good solution here to obtain the token or to verify the user? If this method isn't recommended, what are some other ways I can said things? Because this is a cron job, there is no interface or javascript to log user in whatsoever, but in the end, I would need to authorize and make sure it is that user that sent the HTTP requests in order to track their quota.

**Question #2**: Since the code inside `cron.php` is completely private, is it a good practice to just assume everything sent from there is safe and not perform any check up (simply increase the quota)? If not, what are some good ways to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the code inside cron.php is completely private, is it a good practice to just assume everything sent from their is safe and not perform any check up

Yes, this is one of the main reasons to put code on a backend - you're in full control of it, and you know it can't be compromised (as long as you're also taking the usual security precautions).

I don't see that there's any reason to try to get a token for end user in this situation.  Just do all the work on behalf of the user.

By the way, you could probably eliminate your PHP code entirely and just run a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that's configured to be invoked every 5 minutes.